# If I use a Java 8 library to code an application and try to compile it using a Java 6 compiler, will/should the build fail?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have Java 8 on my laptop. I used the java.time library to write a small code snippet to calculate application processing time using Eclipse IDE v4.9 (2018-09 release). The project used Java 1.6 compiler version. I then ran the application on my laptop and it ran without any error and it produced expected output. Then I exported the application into a war file using Java 1.6 compiler to run it in a tomcat 6 server running Java 1.7 vm. I faced the following situation:

1. There was no error in the log file. Log level was set to debug.
2. The application processes database rows and based upon some logic, inserts in 4 different database tables. While the input database table was being polled, valid input rows were not being picked up by the application.
3. I installed Java 7 on my laptop, made Java 7 the workspace JRE and the code snippet threw a compilation error.

My question is, when I am using Java 6 compiler to compile code based upon a Java 8 library, shouldn't the build fail? At no point during the entire exercise was there any error thrown by the application, and it ran successfully on my laptop and produced the expected output (obviously due to my laptop having Java 8 vm). The way I caught the root cause of the problem was pure accident. Is this a Java bug or a known issue?

Update: I am not looking for a solution to a problem. I am looking for an explanation of Java compiler behaviour.

Comment: did you use lambda's or streams? did you use anything that wasn't in Java 6?

Comment: Used only the java.time library. No lambdas or streams.

Comment: so it won't work. The Java8 compiler knows exactly how to handle with Java6 compliant code, because it 's "past knowledge" somewhat embedded. What you would try to do, is have a compiler compile code that couldn't possibly exist (and for which the compiler wouldn't know what to do) when it was created.

Comment: But it did work. The Java 1.6 compiler managed to compile the code and produce a WAR file. When I deployed the WAR file in a tomcat 1.6 server, the application ran without any error. The problem was, it did not do what it was supposed to do, that is read entries from a database table. But there was no application error during runtime, nor any build error during compilation.

Comment: So ... you compiled code that didn't exist in Java 6 with the Java 6 compiler? Call me sceptical, I don't buy it. If the problem is that "it did not do what it was supposed to do", you made logical errors in your code.

Comment: If I had made logical errors in my code, removing the java.time code snippet would not have solved the issue. But it did. Also, I mentioned in the original post that the application was running fine in my laptop, and it was "doing what it was supposed to do", which was because my workspace default JRE was Java 8. The issue started once I tried to run the application in a Java 7 Tomcat server. But, as I mentioned, there was no error. If you are still not convinced, share your mailing info, I will send you the steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Package `java.time` was introduced only in Java 8. So if you use it your code won't work on previous JVM versions.

You should change your Tomcat's JVM version or remove the `java.time` dependent code from your project.

Comment: That is not my question. I have fixed the issue by removing java.time dependent code. My question is shouldn't the build fail since I am using an old compiler version?

Comment: I completely depends on your code. It will fail if you use new features in your code which are not supported by an old compiler.

Comment: That's where I am stumped, as the compilation did not fail. Nor was there any runtime error when I deployed the WAR file built with Java 1.6 compiler in a Tomcat 1.6 server.

Comment: JVM has backward compatibility. If you compile your code with 1.6 compiler and run it on JVM 1.7 (for example) or higher - it will work correctly. But, if you compile your code with 1.7 compiler and run it on JVM 1.6, it may fail if you're using new features which are not introduced in the older JVM version.

Comment: JVM compatibility is not the issue here. The issue is that the code written using 1.8 library got compiled and exported to WAR using 1.6 compiler, and ran without error in 1.7 JVM, but failed to achieve it's logical goal. It got fixed by removing the 1.8 code snippet. At some point, there should have been an error, and there wasn't. The compiler should not have compiled the code, or exported the WAR, or the logger should have produced an appropriate error. I don't even know what the error should have been in this case, as I've never faced this before, nor have I found something similar online.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven your code going to be run. But you have to be sure that you use functionality only from chosen version of Java.

Comment: Maven is not used. Simple Eclipse tomcat integration is used to run in local, and exported war file to run on RHEL tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could fail if you used feature introduced in java 7+ versions. To quote a few:

1. java.time library.
2. Diamond syntax:
   List list = new ArrayList<>();
3. Lambda or stream functions.
4. Strings in switch statements.
5. forEach() method in Iterable interface.
6. default and static methods in Interfaces.

This is not a complete list but a few examples.

Comment: Therein lies my question, as it did not fail. Is this a known issue or a new Java bug?